# Bad formatting: "Questions about transcribing or finding a particular song &mdash;"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, close-reasons

Today, on the Off Topic Closing Reasons I found this bug:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why an SE staff member removed the tag [meta-tag:bug] from an obvious bug. **You shouldn't be seeing HTML entities in a well-made page.**

Comment: Aye we'll need to go in and edit that. Well spotted :-)

Comment: I would imagine it is because it isn't a bug in SE code, it was a mistake when posting the text.

Comment: Just awaiting another mod to approve the edit then we'll be done

Comment: @DrMayhem It doesn't make it less of a bug. It only makes it a bug that the mods can solve without The Powers interacting.

Comment: Just a spelling mistake - I don't think that's what bug refers to here :-)

Comment: It's definitely somewhat of a bug.  The dash is properly rendered in the box when editing ... just not after it's saved :/